# I am looking for C++ wrapper around built-in Perl functions

Tags: c++, perl, interface, function

A while ago I found a library that allowed calling individual built-in Perl functions in C++, I cannot find it now.

Can you tell me where I can find it on the net?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to try [libperl++](http://github.com/Leont/libperl--). It's still kind of beta, but the part that involves calling perl from C++ has been mature for quite some time. It's much easier to use than the perl API itself.

Full disclosure: I'm the author of libperl++

Answer (score 1):

Read [`perlembed`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlembed.html) and [*Extending and Embedding Perl*](http://www.manning.com/jenness/).

Answer (score -2):

Try the following:

[perl xs c++](http://www.johnkeiser.com/perl-xs-c++.html)

[C::DynaLib](http://metacpan.org/pod/C::DynaLib)

Comment: That works the other way around: calling C++ functions from Perl